# SharePoint List View Filter display 1 week

Tags: filter, sharepoint-fields, sharepoint-views

Our list has a view threshold of 20,000 items, which we usually reach every 12-15 days. Right now it's at 17,456 items and the oldest items are from December 7. So I want to create a filter to display items from the last 7 days including today's. The default **Created** column showed both date and time, so I created a new calculated column called **Created Date** with the formula `=[Created]` and set it to display date only. Then I tried to create a filter like `Created Date is great than or equal to [Today] AND Created Date is less than or equal to [Today]+7` but it's not working. It's only showing records as old as about 10 hours ago, roughly 2000 records. How do I solve this?

*Note 1:* This is the only filter on the list, so there's nothing that should be conflicting with this one. 
 *Note 2:* I only have basic modify view option, modify in sharepoint designer (advanced) is disabled.

Comment: You should be able to use the standard Created column to do what you want. instead of using your Created_Date column

Comment: @Roland really? I read that it wouldn't work using the standard Created column since it contains both date and time. But I guess I can give it a try, thanks.

Comment: That might be the case depending on how sensitive to the time you want it as when Today is created it will be created with a time as well i believe. But for 99% of the time this should be perfectly fine..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should modify your filter to be [Today]-7 , see the details below:

[image]

This should work for you.

Comment: So just the one statement? I don't need  AND / OR ?

Comment: This will get you all the items that were created in the last 7 days.

Comment: Make sure to have no spaces between the number and the keyword, so make it like [Today]-7 .. without spaces